# How can I create an enum from an interface in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, enums, parse-platform

I am building a backend using Parse Server written in Typescript. Parse uses "magic strings" in many places and I am trying to avoid them.

For example, if I have a Parse Class named `Item` and it has an attribute `color`, I would get the property the following way: `myItem.get('color')`.

I am hoping to make this type safe and use an enum for `color` instead of the string itself. I already have an interface defined for all attributes of `Item` like so:

```js
import { Attributes, Object } from 'parse'

export interface ItemAttributes extends Attributes {
  color: string
  size: number
  enabled: boolean
}

export class Item extends Object<ItemAttributes> {
  constructor (data?: Partial<ItemAttributes>) {
    super('Item', data as ItemAttributes)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to generate an enum from the `ItemAttributes` interface in Typescript without having to create a new enum for every Parse Class like so?

```js
export enum ItemKeys {
  color = 'color'
  size = 'size'
  enabled = 'enabled'
}
```

As a result I am hoping to be able to use my new enum in the Parse getter like this:

```js
myItem.get(ItemKeys.color)
```

Comment: You can't make an enum from an interface, but there might be other approaches.  Unfortunately I'm no parse-platform expert so I don't know how to advise further.  If you could remove that dependency (e.g., just provide a standalone example) I might have more insight.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate enums with TS-morph

the documentation is lacking and it is not easy to use
also for the most part all of this is string manipulation
so its not for the faint of heart

you can use chatGPT to generate the exact code you need

with it you can do something like this:

```
        keyValueEnum = enumFile.addEnum({
            name: keyValueEnumName,
            isExported: true,
        });
        keyValueEnum.addMember({
            docs: ['some teext formatted with JS Docs'],
            name: key,
            value: 'A String you want the Value to be',
        });
```